# Icon and text in a flat line on a list

Tags: html, css, list, frontend, icons

Hi guys so basically I am trying to putt some social media logo and next to it i want to write the account detailes or any kind of text next to the icon i am strugling with that because i want to have some movement when someone put the mouse on the icon and here everything screw up so if someone know how to make the text and the icon next to each other at the same time both of them get the same effect when someone putt the mouse on the icon or the text

https://jsfiddle.net/asda12321/9mj5q8k4/1/

```
`<div id="bottom">
    <div id="socia-midea-logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html.html" ><img id="socia-midea-logo" src="../content/ico/facebook.png" alt="insta img"></a></li>
            <h1>Facebook</h1>
            <li><a href="index.html.html"><img id="socia-midea-logo" src="../content/ico/whatsapp.png" alt="insta img"></a></li>
            <h1>Whatsapp</h1>
            <li><a href="index.html.html"><img id="socia-midea-logo" src="../content/ico/instagram.png" alt="insta img"></a></li>
            <h1>Instgram</h1>
            <li><a href="index.html.html"><img id="socia-midea-logo" src="../content/ico/world-wide-web.png" alt="insta img"></a></li>
            <h1>Email</h1>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Css

```
#bottom{
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: turquoise;
}

#socia-midea-logo {
    width: 1em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 1.5em;
    margin: 5em 0em 0em 0em; 
    width: 4em;
}

#socia-midea-logo ul{
    list-style: none;
}



#socia-midea-logo li a:hover{
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 3.7em 2.7em 1.5em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50em;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Always the text goes below the icon only

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of bugs in Yopurs code.

1. You can't mix `H1` and `LI` elements
2. You cant use one id `id="socia-midea-logo"` in more than one element.
3. You should not use H1 without text section. This is not forbidden but it is still small document structure bug.

I suggest do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6jt94pab/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <style>
      .social-media ul{
        list-style: none;
        width:100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
      }

      .social-media li{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        margin:5px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
      }

      .social-media li a{
        display:block;
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        padding-left:60px;
        position:relative;
        color:#555555;
        box-sizing:border-box;
      }

      .social-media li img{    
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:2px;
        width:38px;
        height:38px;
        transition:all 300ms ease;
      }

      .social-media li a:hover{
        color:#0055AA;
        background:#f0f0f0;
        border-radius:5px;
      }

      .social-media li a:hover>img{
        transform:rotate(360deg);
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="social-media">
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174879.png" alt="Facebook">WhatsApp</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/4812/4812397.png" alt="Facebook">Email</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```